# Revit vb.net change IFC Parameter value

Tags: vb.net, parameters, revit-api, ifc

I can change a lot of parameters by the `.LookupParameter("string").SetValueString("new_string")`, but it seems that IFC parameters (or Identify Data) can not be changed? How can they be changed?

I made a new IFC parameter `Balknummer` with value "Balknummer_Balk basis" in my family, but when I tried `_balkcopy.LookupParameter("Balknummer").SetValueString("Balk 1")`, the value stays the same (Balknummer_Balk basis)

Comment: Found it! got to use .Set instead of .SetValueString. The last is only for values (double)

Comment: Can you change it manually in the end user interface? Have you looked at it via RevitLookup and other Revit database exploration tools? Both of those tests might be illuminating. Good luck!